# Pythonic way to create a dict with optional fields

Tags: python, dictionary, option-type, literals

I'd like to create a dict in a list comprehension that might not have some key. So far, I came up with this, but it looks rather [ugly](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

```
{
    "foo": 1,
    <more fields>,
    **({"bar": 2} if bar else {})
}
```

Alternatively,

```
dict(
    foo=1,
    <more fields>,
    **({"bar": 2} if bar else {})
)
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? I'm looking for an *expression* for a dict where some keys might not be present based on a condition.

Comment: What does the source data look like?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're trying to accomplish from your description, but perhaps a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) could be helpful here?

Comment: Your method works.  To improve readability, you may want to consider: `my_dict = {'foo': 1}`, then `if bar: my_dict['bar'] = 2`

Comment: @Alexander I left this out of the snippet, but that don't work in a comprehension.

Comment: You can use `if 'key' not in dict` to or `if dict.get('key') is None` to handle missing keys

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Agreed. You would need to do that step after you instantiate the dictionary via the dict comp.

Comment: Why does it need to be an expression? That is a conditional branch, so of course it will be ugly with any way trying to cram it into an expression.  **Just use an if statement.**  If the syntax necessitates an expression for some reason, put the if statement into a function and use a function call.

Comment: @wim It needs to be an expression in a comprehension. Yes, a function is another way to do this.

Comment: And why does it need to be within a comprehension? It's not Pythonic to try and hack comprehensions to include some complicated flow control - we'll usually prefer plain for-loops and update/append for readability.

Comment: Could you share how you use this within your list comprehension?